# ITK JS readImageDICOMFileSeries() reports 'filePath is undefined' on console

Tags: javascript, itk

I'm new to Javascript and ITK.  I started by cloning the ITK-JS repository, and am working thru the examples.

My objective -- from my browser, to read all of the images in a directory (an MR series) into a single ITK image (3D volume).

I started with the 'webpack' example in the ITK-JS example -- got that working in my browser.

I then:
 1. Changed the index.html to enable `multiple` for the `<input type='file'>` element.  I confirmed that worked properly by writing the contents of the FileList object to the html element, and got that working with the 'readFile()'; then
 2. Replaced the 'readFile(null, files[0])' with 'readImageDICOMFileSeries(null, files)'.

When I run the code with the 'readImageDICOMFileSeries()' I get the console message: "TypeError: filePath is undefined".

I have tried several variants, but always seem to get the same error.  Here is my current code:

```
  //
  //  read the images
  // return readFile(null, files[0])  // -- this line works
  return readImageDICOMFileSeries(null, files)  // the causes TypeError: filePath is undefined 
      .then((worker)=>{
              const {image}=worker;
              let mFile = JSON.stringify(image) ;
              alert(mFile)
              console.log(image);
      })
      .catch(error=>{
              console.error(error);
              alert(error.message);
      })
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Doug

Answer (score 0):

This is an example using ITK and emscripten to compile an ITK library to read most medical image formats. It works in the browser and node.js.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/med-img-reader

I hope it helps. 
There may be additional resources/examples here https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/itk-js/tree/master/examples/